# How to operator "[]" for pointers

Tags: c++

I have a struct T and a enum,such as:

```cpp
struct T{
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
}*pt;
enum {ID = 1,NAME};
```

I want use `pt[ID]` replace `pt->_id` ,use `pt[NAME]` replace `pt->_name`.
I was going to write:

```cpp
int operator[] (int type) {
    if (type == ID)
        return _id;
    else if (type == NAME)
        return name;
}
```

but this code have two error:
1.id's type is int,but name's type is std::string,return type only one.
2.this operator T's "[]",but I want operator T*'s "[]".

Comment: What is the problem with just using `pt->_id` and `pt->_name`?

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to do that? It will be more work, it will make the code less readable and less maintainable. What is the actual and underlying problem that overload is supposed to solve?

Comment: @xihtyM There is nothing wrong with using '->', even pointers should not use "[]", but I want to implement such operations, nothing more.

Comment: As for how to solve your code with your wish, it's not possible. You can't overload the `[]` operator as a non-member function, which means you can't overload it for an arbitrary type like `T*`, which means `pt[...]` will always be pointer dereference. If you overload it as a member function, and solve the multi-return type problem (which is possible but makes the code worse) then you need to do e.g. `(*pt)[ID]` which doesn't really add anything useful to the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just an idea, I know that "[]" should not be used as a pointer, so it won't be used in actual code, but I want to know how to implement this function.There is a limitation of C++ syntax, so I can't implement this function?

Comment: As mentioned, you can not implement this function in the C++ language.  C++ fundamentally relies on knowing the type of any expression at compile time, and you are asking how the return type of a function can be determined by a runtime function argument.

Comment: You could replace `enum` with tags: https://godbolt.org/z/xhxWvn1v8. But this is hardly a good interface, don't do it.

Comment: @Evg This is a great idea, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload the `[]` operator for raw pointers and you cannot change the return type of a function based on a parameter value.

This leaves you with the following option to get close to the desired outcome:

- Implement a custom type that provides the operations of a pointer.
- Go with globals of different types instead of enum constants and provide overloads for the `[]` operator.

```
struct T
{
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
};

// type aliases for ease of use/readability of the code below;
// the enum values are encoded in the type instead
using IdType = std::integral_constant<int, 1>;
using NameType = std::integral_constant<int, 2>;

class Ptr
{
    T* m_ptr;
public:
    constexpr Ptr(T* ptr)
        : m_ptr(ptr)
    {
    }

    constexpr auto& operator[](IdType) const
    {
        return m_ptr->_id;
    }

    constexpr auto& operator[](NameType) const
    {
        return m_ptr->_name;
    }

    // not sure, if the following 2 are needed/desired
    T* operator->() const
    {
        return m_ptr;
    }

    T& operator*() const
    {
        return *m_ptr;
    }
};

inline constinit IdType ID {};
inline constinit NameType NAME {};

// check, that we actually get references to the correct types with the [] operator
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<Ptr>()[ID]), int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<Ptr>()[NAME]), std::string&>);
```

Example use:

```
T t{};
Ptr pt = &t;
pt[ID] = 1;
pt[NAME] = "John Doe";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my boring idea and giving such an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to overload operators on pointer types, only on class types.

It is also not possible to have the type of an expression depend on the value of its operands. It can only depend on the type of the operands. Both `ID` and `NAME` have the same type, so `pt[ID]` and `pt[NAME]` also must have the same type, which is not what you are trying to do.

C++ is statically typed. You cannot have types of expressions be dependent on runtime decisions at all.

Comment: Can I use templates 、define 、std::any or std::variant to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @NeC No. But whatever actual problem you are trying to solve probably may be. You are not explaining that in the question and instead only ask how to implement one specific syntax you want. That syntax is simply impossible, so I can't tell you anything more without additional information about your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to return a value whose type will be different depending on the argument at runtime, you would need to use something like `variant`. This is based on your code:

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>
 
struct T
{
    int _id;
    std::string _name;

    std::variant<int, std::string> operator[](int field)
    {
        switch (field)
        {
            case 0: return _id;
            case 1: return _name;
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("No such field");
    }
};
```

By itself it's difficult to see what this would achieve. It's the kind of thing you might do if you were implementing a dynamic scripting language, though you would have a lot more still to do.

To safely retrieve the value from the variant is not complicated but would be extremely awkward and verbose compared to just using a dynamic language:

```
if (v.index() == 0) stream << std::get<int>(v);
if (v.index() == 1) stream << std::get<std::string>(v);
```

It's likely what you're trying to do is not a great fit for C++.

Comment: Good idea, but it seems that using std::variant variables is a bit cumbersome